# laravel-routing how do i convert this into Resource

Tags: laravel

```
Route::get('/teacher', [
   'uses' => 'AppController@getTeacherPage',
   'as' => 'teacher',
   'middleware' => 'roles',
   'roles' => ['Admin', 'Teacher']
]);
```

how do i convert this into Resource

I tried something like

```
Route::resource('teacher',TeacherController, [
   'uses' => 'TeacherController@index',
   'as' => 'teacher',
   'middleware' => 'roles',
   'roles' => ['Admin', 'Teacher']
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::resource('teachers',TeacherController, [
   'names' => [
       'teachers' => 'teachers.index',
       'teacher' => 'teachers.show'
   ],
   'middleware' => 'roles',
   'roles' => ['Admin', 'Teacher']
]);
```

Will match `index()` and `show($id)` functions.